# Correct mvn version for dispatch.databinder.net

Tags: scala, maven, scala-dispatch

The last version of the library dispatch.databinder.net is 0.9.5, according to the [website](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html).

What is the correct mvn dependency?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.databinder.dispatch</groupId>
  <artifactId>core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.databinder.dispatch</groupId>
  <artifactId>dispatch-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

or something else?

and how to find out this in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the website says

```
libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.9.5"
```

The corresponding maven notation for Scala 2.10.x should be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.databinder.dispatch</groupId>
  <artifactId>dispatch-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Starting sbt 0.12.0, the Scala version postfix got shortened to `_2.10` for Scala 2.10.x and above to take advantage of binary compatibilities between minor releases of Scala.