# Simple ScalaXB example causes NoSuchMethodError in Dispatch

Tags: scala, soap, wsdl, scala-dispatch, scalaxb

I am new to Scala and I was trying out an example with [ScalaXB](http://scalaxb.org/).

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and the latest Scala version 2.10.1.

ScalaXB uses [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net) so I added that (version 0.9.5) as a dependency to the project. I also had to add as a dependency slf4j-nop:1.6.2. So, afterwards everything compiled but an exception keeps appearing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Lscala/Function0;)Lscala/Either;
at dispatch.Promise$class.result(promise.scala:64)
at dispatch.ListenableFuturePromise.result(promise.scala:223)
at dispatch.Promise$class.apply(promise.scala:75)
at dispatch.ListenableFuturePromise.apply(promise.scala:223)
at scalaxb.DispatchHttpClients$DispatchHttpClient$class.request(httpclients_dispatch.scala:12)
at scalaxb.DispatchHttpClients$$anon$1.request(httpclients_dispatch.scala:4)
at scalaxb.SoapClients$SoapClient$class.soapRequest(soap12.scala:32)
at scalaxb.SoapClients$$anon$1.soapRequest(soap12.scala:14)
at scalaxb.SoapClients$SoapClient$class.requestResponse(soap12.scala:51)
at scalaxb.SoapClients$$anon$1.requestResponse(soap12.scala:14)
at eu.getintheloop.sample.XMLProtocol$WeatherSoap12Bindings$WeatherSoap12Binding$class.getWeather(xmlprotocol.scala:53)
at eu.getintheloop.sample.XMLProtocol$WeatherSoap12Bindings$$anon$3.getWeather(xmlprotocol.scala:48)
at eu.getintheloop.sample.main$.main(main.scala:20)
at eu.getintheloop.sample.main.main(main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

The code line is:

```
protected lazy val result = allCatch.either { claim }
```

This looks quite strange because "claim" appears to be a perfectly good java.lang.String object:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<GetWeatherResponse xmlns="http://litwinconsulting.com/webservices/">
<GetWeatherResult>Sunny</GetWeatherResult>
</GetWeatherResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` on Scala standard library stuff, my guess is that somewhere along the setup of IntelliJ or sbt, you're using non-2.10.1 Scala compiler or library.

**Edit**: Per dispatch, please see my answer for [correct mvn version for dispatch.databinder.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508401/correct-mvn-version-for-dispatch-databinder-net/15508707#15508707). You don't have to build it yourself.

Comment: Apparently, the dispatch binary from the ivy dependency was build only for scala 2.9.2. I got the project and had to rebuild it with scala 2.10.1. Thanks.